# Accessing a git repository via ssh behind a firewall

Tags: git, proxy, openssh, jsch

I would like to access (clone/push/pull) a private (via ssh) git repository while behind a corporate firewall that only allows http proxy access. I have written a robust Java (daemon) program (based on the JSCh class library) that will allow me to leverage local and remote port forwarding and I am hoping to leverage this but my brain hurts when I try to envision how to set this up.

The git repo depot (to coin a phrase) is at foo.server.com/var/git so the natural inclination, ignoring the fireall, to set up a clone would be:

```
$ git clone ssh://foo.server.com/var/git/myrepo.git
```

but the firewall will block this command.  I'm inclined to try something like

```
$ git clone ssh://localhost:8022/var/git/myrepo.git
```

where localhost:8022 is forwarded to foo.server.com:22

So is this path worth pursuing?  Is there any easier solution that is still secure?  Are there pitfalls or gotchas I should be aware of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you get a normal ssh (command-line) session going? If so, git should also work.

When using ssh, git should pick up your configuration options in .ssh/config.
If that is not enough, you can point the environment variable GIT_SSH at a modified version of ssh (or shell script wrapper).

Comment: No.  That's what is making this so hard.  Only http is allowed through the firewall.  There are SSH configuration hacks that I can use to get  normal ssh commands to work but I do not believe these will help with the git command.  I'd love to hear that I'm wrong and I will try this out when I get to work.

Comment: Updated my answer: your SSH config hacks should work via git, too.

Comment: Actually git simply invokes `git-upload-pack` / `git-receive-pack` when doing fetch / push via SSH (it does something like `ssh git.example.com "git-upload-pack '/project.git'"`). You can specify where to find git-upload-pack or git-receive-pack using appropriate options to git-fetch / git-push.

Comment: @pajato0: Could you post a bit more detailed answer what you actually did here? I.e. what did you use as GIT_SSH?

Comment: Sure.  I set GIT_SSH=sshx where sshx is a command on my PATH variable that specifies a configuration file which uses corkscrew to bypass the firewall, i.e. sshx is "ssh -F ~/path/to/xconfig $*" and xconfig contains (under Host *) "ProxyCommand corkscrew proxy-host.foo.com 80 %h %p /path/to/proxyauth"

Answer (score 40):

Using `socat` and a `.ssh/config` like this:

```
Host=foo.server.com
ProxyCommand=socat - PROXY:your.proxy.ip:%h:%p,proxyport=3128,proxyauth=user:pwd
```

You should be able to `ssh` to `foo.server.com` and

```
git clone ssh://foo.server.com/var/git/myrepo.git
```

is expected to work.

Comment: Nice, this is the final solution for this annoying problem. Awesome! [Small post about this](http://albertgroothedde.com/post/2017-04-fix-ssh-and-git-clone-behind-proxy-on-macos/)

Comment: Thanks Gregor, your solution worked! Proxies are such a pain to deal with. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

This is my setup working under a Linux machine (localhost on port 18081 is a proxy).

```
cat ~/.ssh/config
Host  github.com
  User git
  ProxyCommand nc -x localhost:18081 -Xconnect %h %p
```

Comment: On Debian this requires the package "netcat-openbsd" (the version of netcat provided by "netcat-traditional" does not have the -x option).

Answer (score -1):

When you do `git clone http://example.com/gitproject.git` or `git clone https://example.com/gitproject.git`, you're using the HTTP/HTTPS protocol.

Git respects http_proxy and https_proxy envrionment variables, so you can simply execute the following command in a shell:

```
export http_proxy=socks5://localhost:1080 https_proxy=socks5://localhost:1080
```

After that, your git command under the same shell will use the proxy for HTTP/HTTPS connections.