# How to configure Git to clone a repository from GitHub behind a proxy server

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, ssh

I encountered a problem about Git on GitHub on my Ubuntu installation.

I have configured a proxy setting by `git config --global http.proxy proxyserver:port`.

But when I type `git clone git@github.com:myusername/example.git`, I get the following:

Error:

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What should I do?

Comment: You're attempting to connect with `ssh`, which does not use the HTTP proxy settings. You may need to use an HTTP or HTTPS URL on Github.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728934/accessing-a-git-repository-via-ssh-behind-a-firewall) can help it.

Comment: I use the https url to clone the repo, and it work.

Answer (score 2):

I follow the steps below to access git respositories from behind a corporate proxy. This method works for git repositories using git URLs like "git://something.git"; *for git repositories using http URLs like "http://something.git" use the accepted answer for this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server) instead.*

This version uses corkscrew and sets a username and password required by the proxy.

Install corkscrew (Ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install corkscrew
```

Create credentials file containing your proxy username and password

```
echo "username:password" > ~/.corkscrew-auth
```

In my case the credentials look like this

```
domain\username:password
```

Secure auth file

```
chmod 600 ~/.corkscrew-auth
```

Create corkscrew wrapper script ~/scripts/corkscrew.wrapper

```
#!/bin/sh
exec corkscrew PROXY_IP_ADDRESS PROXY_PORT $* ~/.corkscrew-auth
```

Make the script executable

```
chmod +x ~/scripts/corkscrew.wrapper
```

Configure git

```
git config --global core.gitproxy ~/scripts/corkscrew.wrapper
```

Test if you can clone a repository

```
git init
git clone git://SOME_GIT_REPOSITORY_ADDRESS
```

In case you want to clean the git configuration you just made

```
git config --global --unset core.gitproxy
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Install corkscrew

```
$ sudo apt-get install corkscrew
```

Step 2 : Write a script named git-proxy.sh and add the following

```
#!/bin/sh

exec corkscrew <name of proxy server> <port> $*

# <name_of_proxy_server> and <port> are the ip address and port of the server
# e.g. exec corkscrew 192.168.0.1 808 $*
```

Step 3 : Make the script executable

```
$ chmod +x git-proxy.sh
```

Step 4 : Set up the proxy command for GIT by setting the environment variable

```
$ export GIT_PROXY_COMMAND="/<path>/git-proxy.sh"
```

Now use the git commands,such as

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
```

Comment: could you please help me with - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600830/ssh-ing-to-remote-server-from-behind-a-proxy